# Libre Office Forms auto functions

Tags: libreoffice

In my Libre Office database, on my data entry form I want to add some automatic functions like in a spreadsheet.  For example, if a user enters a date in the form, can the "Weekend" boolean be automatically be switched to yes.

As well as, can the hours worked be automatically calculated based on the clock in and out times?

Thanks for your help.

[Scrnsht of Data Entry Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ogt6G.png)